# How to resolve null pointer exception during camera capture in Android

Tags: android

How to resolve null pointer exception that occurred when I try to use `Intent.putExtra()` in calling camera activity.

```
public class ImageCaptureActivity extends Activity { 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/gift2.JPG"));

Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  <br>             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ImageCaptured",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();     
Bitmap mBitmap = null;     
try {    
mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),chosenImageUri);    
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
// TODO Auto-generated catch block 
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}     
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);           
img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);    
setContentView(img);   
}   
}   
}
```

When I execute this class . After capturing image through camera and clicking "ok" I am getting null pointer exception at the statement

`"Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();`"

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the output or stacktrace of the exception.  That will make it much easier for us to help you.

Also, null pointer exceptions most commonly occur when trying to use a variable that hasn't been initialized or a value returned by a method that can return null without it checking for null afterward.

Comment: I updated  code. And also mentioned the line where null pointer exception is coming. Can any one help me in sorting out this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camera Application will not work in emulator with 2.2 Version. Try with 2.1 or less. Its  working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image before set on the image view solve your problem ....

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

```
int width = bm.getWidth();

int height = bm.getHeight();
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();`enter code here`
// RESIZE THE BIT MAP
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
        matrix, false);

return resizedBitmap;
```

}